# Saving changes of Entity Framework in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, methods, save

I have created an entity Appraiser and there are methods to select values, display data etc.
Now I want to save the changes made after data is displayed, I have a button named SAVE, which will be used to save changes.
I am not able to get how to save the changes of this Entity?

Entity name is Appraiser, and I have created methods like get AppriaserDetails etc in DAL, BL and used them in aspx.cs.

This is my code:

```
 public void UpdateData(Appraiser appId)
    {

        var Appsave = context.Appraisers.FirstOrDefault(App => App.AppraiserId == appId.AppraiserId);
        Appsave.AppraiserName = appId.AppraiserName;
        Appsave.AppraiserPhones = appId.AppraiserPhones;
        Appsave.AppraiserAppraiserCompanyId = appId.AppraiserAppraiserCompanyId;
        Appsave.Address = appId.Address;
        Appsave.City = appId.City;
        Appsave.ProvinceState = appId.ProvinceState;
        Appsave.Email = appId.Email;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to insert new record, then can use

```
        MyContext.Appraisers.AddObject(appraiserEntityObject);
        MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

In case of update

```
        if (appraiserEntityObject.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            // In case of web, we got an existing record back from the browser. That                object is not attached to the context yet.
            MyContext.Appraisers.Attach(appraiserEntityObject);
            MyContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(appraiserEntityObject,  EntityState.Modified);
        }
        MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

Here MyContext is ur ObjectContext

Comment: Where I will have to write the above code? In the aspx.cs in Buttonsave_click event?

Comment: Ideally in ur DAL, and from ur aspx call some BL function, which will then call a DAL function. If u have referenced the ObjectContext in ur web project, then u can also call it from aspx.cs, but you should avoid doing that

Comment: I am still not getting it, can you tell me in that method in DAL, will I have to pass some id, or it will be the void function?

Comment: In ur aspx.cs, are u creating an entity object??? like new appraiserEntity() and assigning the respective values into the properties, if yes, then pass that object to the BL and DAL functions

Comment: What should be the function parameters in the Bl, I am getting an error when I am calling the same by creating GetUpdate method.